Getting HTTP ERROR 405 when accessing reset password URL in ASP.NET Core Web API
I'm encountering an issue when attempting to reset a password in my ASP.NET Core Web API application. Upon navigating to the reset password URL generated by the system, I receive an HTTP ERROR 405. Here's the URL I'm redirected to:
http://localhost:5181/api/authentication/reset-password?validEmailToken=CfDJ8AKMVdzkx%2BtOiWaFsbCvrZzc9ONeqD2FnOoZXytsyy5Aa%2FCT67TmjnVr2wiExF2g72BoT0w1IiZWgrtl03WQ9gnVNp698fnpV9ldbS8AU0EBg9qVo8SlRHwOgfEVwTu524K82X1m4SlE4ETp5LhE7839tXyLw%2FrA%2Bj3xYNJLJHfmp3%2FJz7AF%2BVitmYf4mYG%2F37tGNJoaLtwTaZ%2BDMZ%2FXUg0iMP6gGC4COz%2BQ7wv2Hu4w
Additionally, here's the relevant code snippets:
public class EmailService(ISmtpService _smtpService)
{
    public async Task<ErrorOr<Success>> SendResetPasswordEmailAsync(
        string email, string token, string baseUrl, string userName)
    {
      string url = $"{baseUrl}api/authentication/reset-password?email={email}&" + $"validEmailToken={WebUtility.UrlEncode(token)}";


        string emailBody = string.Empty;

        using (StreamReader reader = new("./EmailTemplates/forgot-password.html"))
        {
            emailBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        emailBody = emailBody.Replace("{{ name }}", userName);

        emailBody = emailBody.Replace("{{ url }}", url);

        await _smtpService.SendEmailAsync(email, "Reset password", emailBody);

        return Result.Success;
    }
}

public class UserAuthenticationService : IUserAuthenticationService
{
    private readonly UserManager<UserEntity> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<UserEntity> _signInManager; 
    private readonly ILogger<ChangeEmailCommandHandler> _logger; 

    public UserAuthenticationService(UserManager<UserEntity> userManager, SignInManager<UserEntity> signInManager, ILogger<ChangeEmailCommandHandler> logger)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _logger = logger;
    }
    
    public async Task<string> GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(UserEntity user)
    {
        var token = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);

        return token;
    }

    public async Task<ErrorOr<Success>> ResetPasswordAsync(UserEntity user, string token, string password)
    {
        var resetPasswordResult = await _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, token, password);

        if (resetPasswordResult.Succeeded)
        {
            return Result.Success;
        }
        else
        {
            return Error.Validation(resetPasswordResult.Errors.FirstOrDefault()?.Description.ToString());
        }
    }

    public async Task<ErrorOr<UserEntity>> ChangePasswordAsync(UserEntity user, string currentPassword, string newPassword)
    {
        var changePassword = await _userManager.ChangePasswordAsync(user, currentPassword, newPassword);

        if (!changePassword.Succeeded)
        {
            return Error.Validation(changePassword.Errors.FirstOrDefault()!.Description.ToString());
        }

        return user;
    }
}

public class ForgotPasswordQueryHandler 
    : IRequestHandler<ForgotPasswordQuery, ErrorOr<Success>>
{
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;
    private readonly IUserAuthenticationService _userAuthenticationService;
    private readonly EmailService _emailService;
    private readonly IJwtGenerator _jwtGenerator;

    public ForgotPasswordQueryHandler(IUserRepository userRepository, IUserAuthenticationService userAuthenticationService, EmailService emailService, IJwtGenerator jwtGenerator)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
        _userAuthenticationService = userAuthenticationService;
        _emailService = emailService;
        _jwtGenerator = jwtGenerator;
    }
    
    public async Task<ErrorOr<Success>> Handle(ForgotPasswordQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var errorOrUser = await _userRepository.GetByEmailAsync(request.Email);
        if (errorOrUser.IsError)
        {
            return Error.Validation("User with this email doesn't exist");
        }

        var user = errorOrUser.Value;
        string token = await _userAuthenticationService.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
        string? userName;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.FirstName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.LastName))
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.LastName) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.FirstName))
            {
                userName = user.Email;
            }
            else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.LastName))
            {
                userName = user.FirstName;
            }
            else
            {
                userName = user.LastName;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            userName = user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName;
        }

        var sendEmailResult = await _emailService
            .SendResetPasswordEmailAsync(user.Email!, token, request.BaseUrl, userName);

        return sendEmailResult;
    }
}

[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[AllowAnonymous]
public class AuthenticationController : ApiController
{
    private readonly ISender _mediatr;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    
    public AuthenticationController(ISender mediatr, IMapper mapper, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _mediatr = mediatr;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    [HttpGet("forgot-password")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ForgotPasswordAsync([FromQuery]String email)
    {
        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync(email);

        var baseUrl = _configuration.GetRequiredSection(
            "HostSettings:ClientURL").Value;

        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync(baseUrl);

        var query = new ForgotPasswordQuery(email, baseUrl);

        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync(query.Email);

        var forgotPasswordResult = await _mediatr.Send(query);

        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync(forgotPasswordResult.ToString());

        return forgotPasswordResult.Match(
            forgotPasswordRes => Ok(forgotPasswordResult.Value),
            errors => Problem(errors));
    }
}


However, when I click on the reset password link received in the email, instead of being directed to the password reset page, I'm encountering an HTTP ERROR 405. I've double-checked the code and the URL format, but I'm still unable to identify the root cause of this issue.

Look of the line, where you have HttpGet in AuthenticationController. Is the name right ("forgot-password)?
